# Google app engine service account to start Cloud Compute instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to start Google Compute Engine instances from within App Engine itself using APP (not personal) credentials? We can use an app-specific service account for Cloud Storage and Cloud SQL, but can we also use this service account for Compute Engine?

Compute Engine is not listed under services: https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/?hl=en#services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this. Here is a Python demo:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-appengine-demo-suite-python/blob/master/demo-suite/demos/fractal/main.py